# Enabling FIPS on a luks encrypted CentOS system breaks boot password

Tags: centos, rhel, encryption, cryptsetup, crypttab

For one of my apps I need to enable FIPS for OpenSSL, while simultaneously using software disk encryption.

**VM #1**

I launched a CentOS VM instance which was software encrypted during install.  The system booted fine (after entering the boot decryption password).

Next, I went through the steps [to enable FIPS-OpenSSL](https://niranjanmr.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/rhel6-fips/) and rebooted.  The system would not accept my boot decryption password (which was purposely easy to type).

**VM #2**

I set up a second VM with an otherwise identical OS/config *without software encryption*.  I enabled FIPS using the steps above, rebooted, and everything works fine with no problems rebooting.

**VM #3**

I spun up a third CentOS VM instance, also opting not to use system encryption during installation.  After install and basic configuration, I encrypted a test volume using luks, then rebooted.  I'm prompted for the password and the system then boots normally.

Next, I [enabled FIPS-OpenSSL](https://niranjanmr.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/rhel6-fips/), rebooted - and get a plethora of errors where I'd usually see the boot password, and the system does not boot.

I booted this VM into single user mode, pulled fips=1 from the kernel line and rebooted. The boot password was accepted this time.

...

**Why is enabling FIPS for OpenSSL causing the boot passwords to fail?**

Comment: Which version of CentOS? My guess is that your LUKS install used a non-FIPS approved algorithm.  Run `sudo cryptsetup status /dev/mapper/<whatever it is called here>` and check the cipher and keysize conform with the FIPS standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I encrypted the volumes before enabling FIPS.   As [garethTheRed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29406/gareththered) alluded to in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226661/enabling-fips-on-a-luks-encrypted-centos-system-breaks-boot-password?noredirect=1#comment385369_226661), LUKS used a non FIPS approved algorithm, so when FIPS was enabled things went bonkers.

The solution is to

1. Enable FIPS
2. Encrypt volumes

In that order.

[This guide](http://geekswing.com/geek/how-to-encrypt-a-filesystem-on-redhat-6-4centos-6-4-linux-fips-or-no-fips/) was also useful in solving the problem.  It is lengthy with extra explanation so I won't copy paste the full thing here.  Here's the jist:

**A. ENABLE FIPS**

1. Check if FIPS is enabled using one of two methods:

   ```
   cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
   0 = not enabled
   1 = enabled

   openssl md5 /any/file
   valid hash = not enabled
   "Error setting digest md5" = enabled (likely)
   ```
2. Check if you have prelinking turned on.

   ```
   vi /etc/sysconfig/prelink

   Change
   PRELINKING=yes
   to
   PRELINKING=no
   ```
3. Undo all current prelinking

   ```
   [root@centos64]# prelink -ua
   ```
4. Install `dracut-fips`

   ```
   [root@centos64]# yum install dracut-fips
   ```
5. Rebuild your initramfs

   ```
   [root@centos64]# dracut -f
   ```
6. Find device path of `/boot`

   ```
   [root@centos64]# df /boot
   Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
   /dev/sda2         487652 115447    346605  25% /boot
   ```
7. `cp /etc/grub.conf /etc/grub.bak`
8. Edit `/etc/grub.conf`

   ```
   Add in the "fips=1" and "boot=/dev/***" lines to the kernel command line 

   Example: 
   kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_centos6464bittempl-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_centos6464bittempl/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_centos6464bittempl/lv_root rd_NO_MD crashkernel=auto SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet fips=1 boot=/dev/sda2
   ```
9. Reboot
10. Check if FIPS is enabled (See Step 1 above).

**B. ENCRYPT VOLUME**

1. *Are you sure FIPS is enabled?  If not, do not proceed - go back to **ENABLE FIPS** and make sure that part is working before continuing...*
2. Get the device path of the logical volume you wish to encrypt.  In my example, this is `/dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03`
3. BACK UP ALL DATA ON THIS VOLUME.  It will be DESTROYED.
4. `umount` volume.

   In my case, `umount /db_fips`
5. `shred -v -n1 /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03`
6. Encrypt volume and set passphrase

   ```
   cryptsetup -v --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03
   ```

   **NOTE**: a RHEL minimal install may not include cryptsetup by default.  Just `yum install cryptsetup` to get what you need.  CentOS 6.7's minimal package set includes `cryptsetup`.
7. Open the device and alias it to “somename” of your choice  (in this case, "db_fips")

   ```
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03 db_fips
   ```
8. Verify mapper has the path

   ```
   [root@centos64]# ls /dev/mapper/db_fips

   At this point, treat /dev/mapper/db_fips as you would any ordinary filesystem or device
   ```
9. Create filesystem as you normally would

   ```
   [root@centos64]# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/db_fips
   ```
10. Mount it and verify it

    ```
    [root@centos64]# mount /dev/mapper/db_fips /db_fips
    [root@centos64]# date >> /db_fips/today.txt
    ```
11. **¡¡¡IMPORTANT!!!**: Comment out the existing `/etc/fstab` entry for the target volume, lest you have headaches on reboot. `:-)`

    `vi /etc/fstab`

    `# /dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03 /some/path ext4 defaults 1,2`
12. Reboot to ensure the steps above are working.
13. get `UUID` of encrypted volume

    `blkid`

    `/dev/mapper/vg_mybox-LogVol03: UUID="2e52ffee-7a02-4c91-b6bf-223b05f90ded" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"`
14. Add encrypted volume to `/etc/crypttab` - so it can be decrypted on boot.  You can specify a passfile here, but it is not recommended.  *Install DRAC in the server if it is to be remotely administered (so you can enter the pass phrase during boot).*  [crypttab man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crypttab)

    ```
    [root@centos64]# vi /etc/crypttab

    db_fips UUID="2e52ffee-7a02-4c91-b6bf-223b05f90ded"
    ```
15. Reboot to test.